# trying to elminate from rows with dates closer than 5 minutes to each other

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to count all the rows in a MySQL table omitting the records with same `agent` and `msisnd` columns and dates closer than 5 minutes to each other.
For example,

```
id     type    agent              msisdn     date
2706   jurnal  EC_Catalin.Silvan  745844472  2011-02-18 18:31:54
63535  item    EC_Adelina.Gartan  766699747  2011-02-22 18:42:15
56513  item    EC_Adelina.Gartan  766733667  2011-02-24 17:13:31
56372  item    EC_Adelina.Gartan  766733667  2011-02-24 17:12:01
```

The query should return COUNT = 3 because the rows with id's 56513 and 56372 have close dates to each other.

So far i've got this query and it's not working

```
SELECT `calls_count_pre`.*
    FROM `calls_count_pre`
    LEFT JOIN `calls_count_pre` AS `temp` ON (`calls_count_pre`.`id` = `temp`.`id`)
WHERE
    (MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(`calls_count_pre`.`date`, `temp`.`date`)) <= 5 AND HOUR(TIMEDIFF(`calls_count_pre`.`date`, `temp`.`date`)) = 0)
    AND `calls_count_pre`.`msisdn` = `temp`.`msisdn`
    AND `calls_count_pre`.`agent` = `temp`.`agent`
ORDER BY `calls_count_pre`.`agent`, `calls_count_pre`.`msisdn`, `calls_count_pre`.`date` DESC
```

It's simply returning all records. I know I'm not selecting a COUNT, but even a `SELECT *` would be a start at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with a self-join, but I think you might be joining on the wrong column. And I think you're going to need a `GROUP BY` as well.

Try with something more like this:

```
SELECT calls_count_pre.*
   FROM calls_count_pre
   LEFT JOIN calls_count_pre AS temp
        ON calls_count_pre.msisdn = temp.msisdm AND calls_count_pre.agent = temp.agent
        AND temp.date > calls_count_pre.date
        AND DATESUB(temp.date, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) < calls_count_pre.date
GROUP BY calls_count_pre.agent
```

Comment: If I use this query, is still return all rows... Also, I can`t use GROUP BY because I need to see the number of rows resulted after I execute the query. Thank you for your reply